# Ping response contain subnet ip

Tags: network-scanners

One of my friends site got hacked recently. Now while pinging the site `ping zyz.com` the response is like

> From 10.x.0.1 icmp_seq=79 Packet filtered

From what I have heard, 10.x.0.1 looks like a LAN gateway address.

Could someone please help by telling me why is the response having subnet detail in it? Any help would do, Google-ing dint help much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP addresses starting with 10.* are reserved for local area networks. You seem to be on a LAN which does not allow you to ping any host outside of it. 10.x.0.1 seems to be a border-router which filters your pings.